# Do you have to fork a project on github before you can make a pull request?

Tags: github

I dont know if this is the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, yes. If you don't have write access to the repository already, you have to create a fork before you can create a pull request.

See [Creating a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) for step-by-step instructions.